Foreign key constraint is incorrectly two foriegn keys migrate in laravel 11
I am creating a simple warehouse management system in laravel 11. When I tried to migrate tables and assign the foreign keys, I ran into the problem where there foreign key constraint is wrong. What I tried is the migration file, and the full error is attached below.
Error
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `dbwarehourse`.`order_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `order_products` add constraint `order_products_order_id_foreign` foreign key (`order_id`) references `orders` (`id`))

Product table
  Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('productcode');
          

            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories');
            $table->string('productname');
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->integer('stock_level'); // Add this line
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);

            $table->timestamps();
        });

Order table
  Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->interger('invoicenumber');
            $table->foreignId('client_id')->constrained('clients');
            $table->decimal('total_amount', 10, 2);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Order_products
        Schema::create('order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products');
            $table->foreignId('order_id')->constrained('orders');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();

        });


Look at the error message closely. Specifically, look at the SQL that it spit out.

run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and see the LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section

The error you are getting is for assigning order_id foreign_key in  order_products table.
Though the syntax is correct but still there might be some nameing convention issue.I have also face similar situation in my own case.And I found this following solutions helpful.
Since the error says..

(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
(Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table order_products add constraint
order_products_order_id_foreign foreign key (order_id) references
orders (id))

So avoid using constrained() method and instead explicitely define Foreign Key Constraints like this in Order_products schema.
     Schema::create('order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            //define foreign key Constraint
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();

      });

Try this ,I think it will resolve the issue.
In case you face any issue let me know.
Scenario 2 :-
Another potential reason of this error is that you created the order_products migration file before the orders migration file. In that case when you run php artisan migrate this clash occur. Because the foreign-key columns (in this case order_id) of Order_products table being created before the creation of actual table orders that it refer to.
If it is the the case then you need to share these to migrations file name. Only then we can say you the proper solutions.

thankssssss.......................................................
